# PHP: Fatal error - operator not supported for strings in

Tags: php

I have the code below and the error I get is

```
PHP: Fatal error -  operator not supported for strings in...
```

I've read through some articles and questions but can't see why this specific example is falling over. I can't see that I am declaring the array as a string.

Any ideas?

**CODE**

```
$a = Array();
foreach ($value as $k => $v) {

    $name = $v["name"];
    $value = $v["value"];

    $a["day_a"] = ($name == "day_a" ? 'true':'false');
    $a["day_b"] = ($name == "day_b" ? 'true':'false');
    $a["day_c"] = ($name == "day_c" ? 'true':'false');
    $a["day_d"] = ($name == "day_d" ? 'true':'false');
    $a["day_e"] = ($name == "day_e" ? 'true':'false');
    $a["day_f"] = ($name == "day_f" ? 'true':'false');

    if (strpos($name, '_radio_') !== false) {
        $string = substr($name,0,5);
        $a[$string] = $value;
    }

    if (strpos($name, '_select_') !== false) {
        $string = substr($name,0,5);
        $split = explode("_",$name);
        $type = $split[3];

        $a[$string][] = Array("type"=>$type,"location"=>$location); // ERROR HERE
    }

    // if name like day_a radio then $day_a is true
    // if $day_a

}
```

**var_dump( $a, $string ); die();**

```
array(6) {
  ["day_a"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["day_b"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["day_c"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["day_d"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["day_e"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["day_f"]=>
  string(5) "false"
}
string(5) "day_c"
```

Comment: print **$string** and check.

Comment: `substr` also returns false

Comment: It's a string as expected and how can substr return false if it hits this error?

Comment: `var_dump( $a, $string ); die();` right before the error please.

Comment: debugging: `var_dump($string, $type, $location, __FILE__.__LINE__);` immediately before the line in error. No need to post the result unless you don't understand what the error is. Add the output to your question rather than post it is comments. It is easier to read as you can format it.

Comment: Even though probably not the main problem: It is a bad idea for sure that you are using the name  `$value` both for the array you loop trough with `foreach` and as a variable inside.

Answer (score 2):

You probably create string on `$a[$string] = $value;` and then tries to append array to it `$a[$string][] = Array(...);`

You can add check:

```
if ( isset($a[$string]) ) {
    throw new Exception("Item ".$string." already exists!");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand sorry - I can create something like $a["someName"][] = .... so why can't I use $string instead i.e. create a key dynamically

Comment: You can, but are you sure that `$a[$string]` doesn't already exist? Try to dump $a and $string before the error and you'll see...

Comment: It does yes but I'd still like to do this functionality as if I have created $a["day_a"] already, I may want to do $a["day_a"]["date"] but with "day_a" being dynamic/variable

Comment: @pee2pee You can't set $a["day_c"] to "false" (string) and then set `$a["day_c"][] = Array(...);`

Comment: so you need to set `$a["day_a"] = Array();` first and then you can do `$a["day_a"][] = Array(...);`

Comment: And it also looks your whole logic is wrong - in each loop you resets all from $a["day_a"] to $a["day_f"]

Comment: Yes - the logic is fixed - was a temporary blip ;-)